# MVC 5 Bootstrap template smartadmin - renderbody

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded and bought the https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/smartadmin-responsive-webapp-WB0573SK0 template, however I cant get it to work in my mvc 5 project properly.

I created my layoutpage using the "blankpage.html" example included in download.

The layout page works fine, but when I add the renderbody call and try to show page through my template. The renderbody call, keeps adding an extra unwanted div.

Which looks like

`<div id="main" role="main">

</div>`
TEXTADDED

and adds the text in the page after that additional div tag.

Althought the page using the template only contain a single word. In other words, my page using the layout contains the text "test". But renderbody generates:

`<div id="main" role="main">
</div>`
TEXTADDED

Do you have any clue? This is my layoutpage

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">-->
    @*@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@

    <title> SmartAdmin </title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Use the correct meta names below for your web application
         Ref: http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- Basic Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- SmartAdmin Styles : Please note (smartadmin-production.css) was created using LESS variables -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/css/smartadmin-production.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/css/smartadmin-skins.css">
    <!-- SmartAdmin RTL Support is under construction
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/css/smartadmin-rtl.css"> -->
    <!-- We recommend you use "your_style.css" to override SmartAdmin
         specific styles this will also ensure you retrain your customization with each SmartAdmin update.
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/css/your_style.css"> -->
    <!-- Demo purpose only: goes with demo.js, you can delete this css when designing your own WebApp -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/css/demo.css">
    <!-- FAVICONS -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/img/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Areas/Admin/Template/img/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- GOOGLE FONT -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,300,400,700">

</head>
<body class="">
    <!-- possible classes: minified, fixed-ribbon, fixed-header, fixed-width-->
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <header id="header">
        <div id="logo-group">

            <!-- PLACE YOUR LOGO HERE -->
            <span id="logo"> <img src="~/Areas/Admin/Template/img/logo-white2.png" alt="SmartAdmin"> </span>
            <!-- END LOGO PLACEHOLDER -->

        </div>


        <!-- pulled right: nav area -->
        <div class="pull-right">

            <!-- collapse menu button -->
            <div id="hide-menu" class="btn-header pull-right">
                <span> <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Collapse Menu"><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i></a> </span>
            </div>
            <!-- end collapse menu -->
            <!-- logout button -->
            <div id="logout" class="btn-header transparent pull-right">
                <span> <a href="login.html" title="Sign Out"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a> </span>
            </div>
            <!-- end logout button -->
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")

        </div>
        <!-- end pulled right: nav area -->

    </header>
    <!-- END HEADER -->
    <!-- Left panel : Navigation area -->
    <!-- Note: This width of the aside area can be adjusted through LESS variables -->
    <aside id="left-panel">

        <!-- User info -->
        <div class="login-info">
            <span>
                <!-- User image size is adjusted inside CSS, it should stay as it -->

                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="show-shortcut">
                    <img src="~/Areas/Admin/Template/img/avatars/sunny.png" alt="me" class="online" />
                    <span>
                        john.doe
                    </span>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>

            </span>
        </div>
        <!-- end user info -->
        <!-- NAVIGATION : This navigation is also responsive

        To make this navigation dynamic please make sure to link the node
        (the reference to the nav > ul) after page load. Or the navigation
        will not initialize.
        -->
        <nav>
            <!-- NOTE: Notice the gaps after each icon usage <i></i>..
            Please note that these links work a bit different than
            traditional hre="" links. See documentation for details.
            -->

            <ul>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="~/admin/" title="Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">Dashboard</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="~/admin/electricitycounterPart/" title="Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">ElAvtal</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="~/admin/alarmcounterpart/" title="Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">LarmAvtal</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="~/admin/realestatecounterpart/" title="Dashboard"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-home"></i> <span class="menu-item-parent">MäklarAvtal</span></a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
        <span class="minifyme"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left hit"></i> </span>

    </aside>
    <!-- END NAVIGATION -->
    <!-- MAIN PANEL -->
    <div id="main" role="main">

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->

        <div id="content">

            @RenderBody()

        </div>
        <!-- END MAIN CONTENT -->

    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN PANEL -->
    <!--================================================== -->
    <!-- PACE LOADER - turn this on if you want ajax loading to show (caution: uses lots of memory on iDevices)-->
    <script data-pace-options='{ "restartOnRequestAfter": true }' src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/pace/pace.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Link to Google CDN's jQuery + jQueryUI; fall back to local -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!window.jQuery) {
            document.write('<script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/libs/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        if (!window.jQuery.ui) {
            document.write('<script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/libs/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"><\/script>');
        }
    </script>

    <!-- JS TOUCH : include this plugin for mobile drag / drop touch events
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/jquery-touch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- CUSTOM NOTIFICATION -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/notification/SmartNotification.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JARVIS WIDGETS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/smartwidgets/jarvis.widget.min.js"></script>
    <!-- EASY PIE CHARTS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/easy-pie-chart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.min.js"></script>
    <!-- SPARKLINES -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY VALIDATE -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY MASKED INPUT -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/masked-input/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY SELECT2 INPUT -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- JQUERY UI + Bootstrap Slider -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/bootstrap-slider/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- browser msie issue fix -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/msie-fix/jquery.mb.browser.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick: For mobile devices -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/plugin/fastclick/fastclick.js"></script>

    <!--[if IE 7]>

    <h1>Your browser is out of date, please update your browser by going to www.microsoft.com/download</h1>

    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Demo purpose only -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/demo.js"></script>

    <!-- MAIN APP JS FILE -->
    <script src="~/Areas/Admin/js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- PAGE RELATED PLUGIN(S)
    <script src="..."></script>-->


    <script type="text/javascript">

        // DO NOT REMOVE : GLOBAL FUNCTIONS!

        $(document).ready(function () {

            pageSetUp();

        })

    </script>
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)*@
    <!-- Your GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE Below -->


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thx alot, it solved it, it turned out I had an extra div in my _viewstart.cshtml which I didn't know about.....

Comment: Cool, dont suppose you could tick the answer for rep :)

Comment: I think i did that now? This is my first question ever on stack so didn't know how to...thx again for your help

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped, cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it you are using Visual Studio 2013? Install the Web Essentials plug in then launch the application, then make browser window smaller - Use the inspect feature to hover over the div in browser - and it should highlight code in Visual Studio that is rendering the div.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a great SmartAdmin integration to MVC .NET tutorial here:

http://myorange.ca/supportforum/question/how-to-integrate-smartadmin-1-4-x-into-asp-net-mvc-5